# Tradingview: how to increase position size?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I want to create simple strategy which a the beginning invest 10% of my equity. If value of asset decreas by 1% I want to decrease my position by 10%. Opposite situation, if value of assets increases by 1% I want to add to position another 10% of my equity.

Is it even possibile to increase size of position in pinescript?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, because the strategy.entry() function accepts a quantity parameter which can be updated with pinescript based on custom rules

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}entry](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry)

That was to increase the position size for the next trade(s)

To increase the position size of a pending trade, that should be possible
For an already opened trade, I don't think that's doable

Comment: docs says that it can be updated only if it is pending

Comment: indeed, I updated my response